# Android - Parcelable | putParcelableArrayListExtra("ListItems", listItems);

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parcelable

I am trying to pass an ArrayList of objects MyItem from one activity to another. From what i understand i need to implement Parcable in MyItem class. So this is what i'va done so far:

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem, Parcelable {
    private LatLng mPosition=null;
    private String aString;

    public MyItem(double lat, double lng, String aString) {
        mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        this.aString= aString;
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return mPosition;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return aString;
    }


    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }


    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //dest.writeLngLat ?
        dest.writeString(postID);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyItem> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<MyItem>() {
        public MyItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyItem(in);
        }

        public MyItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyItem[size];
        }
    };

    private MyItem(Parcel in) {
        //mPosition = in.readLngLat ?
        aString = in.readString();
    }
}
```

**First question**: How could i write LngLat field in writeToParcel and how could i decleare it in MyItem(Parcel in) constructor?

**Second question**: Is this going to be enough so this piece of code could work?

```
                    ArrayList<MyItem> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
                    Iterator<MyItem> items = cluster.getItems().iterator();
                    while (items.hasNext()) {
                        listItems.add(items.next());
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, ClusterPosts.class);
                    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("oO", listItems);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

and then in CluserPosts:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ArrayList<MyItem> post = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("oO");
    for(MyItem item : post){
        Log.d("elaela", item.getString());
    }
```

Comment: `LatLng` is a `Parcelable`, right?

Comment: LatLng is "default" object from google maps api, not implemented by me. But i think it actually is parcelable

Comment: so it is `Parcelable`, then read/write it directly from/to `Parcel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write parcel as -

```
dest.writeDouble(mPosition.latitude);
dest.writeDouble(mPosition.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write latitude and longitude as doubles only to the destination and then form a position.

```
dest.writeDouble(lat);
dest.writeDouble(long);
```